# SQL to Snowflake syntax

Tags: sql-server, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regex-group

I am trying convert SQL Server code to snowflake but didn't find anything helpful.
How can I write the same logic in snowflake? I tried using `regexp_like` but it didn't work.
Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated.

```sql
select * from s_gth 
    where mtext like '%[^a-z]BITS[^a-z]%' 
    OR mtext like 'BITS[^a-z]%' 
    OR mtext like '%[^a-z]BITS' 
    OR mtext like 'BITS'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a case insensitive search, use the 'i' parameter. Otherwise you may omit that. See also [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_like) for more details.

```
with s_gth (id, mtext) as (
    select * from values
    (1,'aBITSz')
    ,(2,'a BITS')
    ,(3,'BITS0z')
    ,(4,'BITS')
    ,(5,'KIBBLE')
)
select * from s_gth 
    where REGEXP_LIKE(mtext, '.*[^a-z]BITS[^a-z].*', 'i') 
    OR REGEXP_LIKE(mtext, 'BITS[^a-z].*', 'i')
    OR REGEXP_LIKE(mtext, '.*[^a-z]BITS', 'i')
    OR REGEXP_LIKE(mtext, 'BITS', 'i')
```

| ID | MTEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | a BITS |
| 3 | BITS0z |
| 4 | BITS |